# How to Get Google My Maps Location Pins in Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a custom map via http://www.google.com/mymaps/ and have added a few locations.

Is there a way for me to retrieve these locations (in lat and lng format) via Google Map Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to export your map as a KML layer. To see how to do that, you can read about it [here](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en).

After that, you will need to import your KML layer to Google Maps. Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

Then you can use [KML Feature Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#kml_feature_details) and use `position` to get lat/long

Comment: in the above example, it seems that we can only get the details when we click on the object in KML layer. Is it possible to retrieve all the object information without clicking on it? Thanks!

Comment: @HeruS Did this worked out for you? can you please share your solution, even I am facing the same issue.