# How to get store location info from my android app

Tags: android, google-maps

This is a [Yokohama BayBike Store location map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1jhQA9-EMSTN0TH6javoFWbR18tM&ll=35.45170408352364%2C139.6363583069458&z=13), I want use these place info from my Android App.

How can I get list of the place ID or GeoJSON from the baybike page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is [Google My Maps](https://support.google.com/mymaps#topic=3188329), and you can't get places coordinates, if you didn't have access to My Maps account for that map. If you have - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30975958/6950238) question of [Heru S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643366/heru-s) and answers.